# Linear algebra: Why do the two methods give the same answer?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let
$A=\left(\begin{array}{cc|c}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)$
and
$B=\left(\begin{array}{cc|c}
1 & a & b \\
1 & 0 & 0
\end{array}
\right)$.

It is given that $A$ and $B$ are row equivalent and our task is to work out $a$ and $b$.

Method 1: $A$ is the reduced row echelon form (rref) of $B$. We reduce $B$ to its rref, denoted by rref$(B)$ as shown:
$\left(\begin{array}{cc|c}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & \frac{b}{a}
\end{array}
\right)$.

By comparing entries of $A$ and rref$(B)$, we have $a=b$.

Method 2: We view $A$ as the augmented matrix of the system of linear equations $x=0$ and $y=1$. We also view rref$(B)$ as the augmented matrix of the system of linear equations $x=0$ and $y=\frac{b}{a}$. Solving [$x=0$ and $y=1$] and [$x=0$ and $y=\frac{b}{a}$], we have $a=b$ as well.

My question is, why do these two methods produce the same answer? Appreciate any feedback and reminder. My linear algebra is rather rusty. Thank you!